# show random entries from SQL databases fade in out with out refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, database

I need to have a website that can echo out random names from a database, then fade them in and out smoothly. the code that i am using currently is refreshing the whole page and it makes the page flicker and the name change is not smooth.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=15;url=index.php>
<title>Student Display</title></head>
<body>
<img src="U" width="499" height="128" alt=""/>
<center>
  <span style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 72px; color: #013b6a;">
  <p>
  <p>
  <p>
      <?php
  //delayed refresh

$db_host = "localhost:/test";
$db_user = "test";
$db_pwd = "password";

$database = "test";
$table = "Sheet1";

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
// Display the name and date
while($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo $row['Firstname'] . " ";
  echo " " . $row['Surname'] . " ";
  echo "<br>";

  echo " " . $row['Year'] . " ";
  }


?>

      </span>

</center>

</body></html>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side only language, so of course your page has to refresh. If you want just 1 page load, you need to send many names to the server and then use JavaScript to change the display.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the code that queries the database with the code that renders the page. You can use AJAX techniques to request a new name from the script that queries the database without a page reload, then use jQuery animation techniques to fade out the old value and fade in the new value.